# Building pricing logic using PHP

Tags: php, logic

Hope y'all are having a wonderful day full of rainbows and roses!

Ok, ok .. I'll get to the point:

I've got a function that accepts multiple parameters and calculates the price of a product based on those parameters. Here's a conceptual example:

```
public function getPrice( $params ) {
    // black magic goes here
    return $price;
}
```

The parameters include:

1. `$params[width]` which ranges all the way from 10 - 72 inches
2. `$params[height]` which ranges from 10 - 44 inches

(There are actually more params, but for the sake of simplicity, I've kept those out).

Now, I have a table in Excel (something like a truth table) with rows that represent the `width` and columns that represent the `height`. The value in the corresponding cell is the `price`.

How could I best implement this pricing strategy in PHP? I thought nested `if` statements would work but got tired after the 10th `if`. Help?

Comment: Depending on what the table in Excel looks like, you could convert it into a PHP array, walk through that array, and fetch the corresponding price

Comment: @Pekka웃 62 columns x 34 rows. That's a big array!

Comment: Big? With 2108 elements? Not really, it won't cause you any problems memory-wise.

Comment: @Pekka웃 size is obviously relative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the information from Excel in a 2D array.

I.e.

```
$prices = array(  // Columns --
                  array(1,2,3), // Rows 
                  array(4,5,6), //  |
                  array(7,8,9)  //  |
               );
```

Then you can look up your price based on width/height by doing:

`return $prices[row][column];`

In your case, row would be width and column would be height.

Some extra work would be required as you have a range starting at 10, so you'd need to subtract 10 from the value you enter.

I.e:

`return $prices[width-10][height-10];`.

Comment: All 62 columns x 34 rows? That's one BIG array!

Comment: @FloatingRock Potentially yes, this is just the solution that requires the least setup. As another comment says, this is usually handled by a Database. In terms of a program though, 62x34 isn't big, it might just be a pain to manually type out (though you'd only have to do it once).

Comment: Using an array for this is not a problem at all. No point in setting up a database if editing a PHP file is convenient enough, and the data doesn't change often

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern gotcha. I'll go stretch my fingers then before taking on this feat!

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just put all that data in your database? Have a row with all values of every parameter, and the accoriding price ? It's just 1 query away ...